# Meshroom - What does FeatureExtraction dots color mean in Image Viewer?

Tags: feature-extraction, photogrammetry, meshroom

I couldn't find any info in the docs. What does each color mean when I check out the features extracted from an image in Meshroom 2021.1?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

After some testing I deducted what they are:

- **Blue:** Features generated in the node "FeatureExtraction".
- **Orange:** Features Matched with other pictures. Generated in "MatchesFeatures" node.
- **Red:** Features used by StructureForMotion (aka, used in reconstruction).